# Better approach to solving filters than if/else

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

In my list method I will be passing several filters from the client side. Currently I have a long list of if/else blocks that get executed based on the params coming in.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach this?

```
def list () {
  println params
  def list = []
  if (params["Column1"] != null) {
    list = Mymodel.createCriteria().listDistinct {
      eq("somecolumn", params["Column1"]);
    }
  }
  else if (params["Column2"] != null) {
    list = Mymodel.createCriteria().list {
      eq("someothercolumn", params["Column2"]);
    }
  }
  else if (params["filter"] == "failed") { 
     list = MyModel.createCriteria().list {
       eq("status", false);
     }
  }
  return list as JSON
}
```

Below are the params I'm getting for few of the requests:

```
[Column1:somevalue, action:[GET:list], controller:somecontroller]
[Somecolumn:someothervalue, action:[GET:list], controller:somecontroller]
```

Is there a pattern I can use to solve this problem before it gets out of hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any pattern involved, but you can drill the code down to few lines by using Elvis operators and removing the redundancy of creating the criteria:

```
def list() {
    def list = []
    def someColumnValue = params.Column1 ?: params.Column2 ?: null
    def statusValue     = params.filter == 'failed'
    list = Mymodel.withCriteria{ //can also use createCriteria
        if(someColumnValue) {
            eq("somecolumn", someColumnValue)
        } else if(statusValue) {
            eq("status", !statusValue)   
        }
    }
    list as JSON
}
```

If the parameters grows in number then you can use something like

```
def someColumnValue = params.Column1 ?: 
                      params.Column2 ?: 
                      params.Column3 ?: 
                      params.Column4 ?: 
                      null
```

If there is only single parameter involved then you can effectively use switch case blocks instead of if else.

Comment: but in the first if block you have `eq("somecolumn",someColumnValue)` how would I determine which column name to run query against. This value would be "color" if params hash had a key called color

Comment: Your question has `somecolumn` for both the cases `Column1` and `Column2`. How would I be able to know you were referring to different columns? :) @Anthony. In that case you can use a map or an Expando object to populate the key as the column name and the value as the actual values passed or just use a GString for the column name if there is strict nomenclature for the parameter names. Update your question, I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the question. Now I'm querying different columns for different parameters

Comment: @Anthony I have not updated my answer yet (stuck in weekend errands and becoming a professor), can you please mention how my present answer was helpful (add it to your question, it will be helpful to others as well).